# Getting a key error, when trying to access the date

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm trying to predict the Covid-19 spread in next 6 months in India.
So I got the dataset from Kaggle.com and I'am trying to write the code.

The last line of code rises the error `Key Error: 'Date'` .

I would need a suggestion for understanding the error message and solving the error.

```
# python
#importing libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendra
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.offline as pyo
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
import folium
from folium import plugins
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10,12
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`

#Initializing the plotly into offline mode.
pyo.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
#after sucessful complition of work, plotly goes to offline. 
cf.go_offline()

#read the data
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\myoge\OneDrive\Desktop\covid_19\covid_19_india.xlsx')
data.head()

#check the dataset have any null values and sum/count those all null values
data.isnull().sum()

#droping the the 'ConfirmedIndianNational' and 'ConfirmedForeignNational' columns.
data.drop(['ConfirmedIndianNational','ConfirmedForeignNational'], axis=1, inplace = True)

#printing the dimentions of the table.
data.shape

#plotting a bar graph to see how many deaths and recovred cases are their in india.
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (25,25))
data = data[['State/UnionTerritory', 'Confirmed','Cured','Deaths']]
data.sort_values('Confirmed', ascending= False, inplace = True)
sns.set_color_codes('pastel')
sns.barplot(x='Confirmed', y='State/UnionTerritory', data = data,label = 'Total', color='red' )
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x='Cured', y='State/UnionTerritory',data = data,label = 'Cured ', color='blue' )
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc='lower right', frameon = True)
ax.set(xlim = (0, 700000), ylabel = '',xlabel = 'Cases')
sns.despine(left = True, bottom = True)

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], dayfirst = True)
```

Comment: Please paste your code and error messages as text rather than as an image. It allows us to copy/paste your code so we can help investigate your issue. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details. Also, please share what `data` is.

Comment: 'data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], dayfirst = True)' while executing this line of code , I got the " KeyError: ' Date' ". here 'data' is a variable name used for read and access the  excel dataset.

Comment: Can you show us what the `data` variable looks like? You can edit your original question rather than adding it as comments to give yourself more room to edit.

Answer (score 2):

The erroneous line is

```
data = data[['State/UnionTerritory', 'Confirmed','Cured','Deaths']]
```

Here you are implicitly dropping the date column.

To fix it, just use

```
data = data[['Date', 'State/UnionTerritory', 'Confirmed', 'Cured', 'Deaths']]
```

I was able to confirm the KeyError and the above fix by using the data file covid_19_india.csv from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/covid19-in-india/).